# Need help regarding Lucene index/query

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I want to have a "citystate" field in Lucene index which will store various city state values like:

- Chicago, IL
- Boston, MA
- San Diego, CA

How do i store these values(shud it be tokenized or non-tokenized?) in Lucene and

how do I generate a query (should it be phrasequery or termquery or something else?) which gets me all records whose citystate contain: Chicago, IL OR Boston, MA OR San Diego, CA ??

I would appreciate if i can get help with the code as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldnt city state be normalized further into two separate fields ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Will you ever want to search by city alone or by state alone? In this case you need to tokenize. If not, do not tokenize. Check out the [KeywordAnalyzer](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.Analysis.KeywordAnalyzer.html), though - it may suit you.

As to your second question. Suppose you call the field 'citystate'. You can then use a query such as:
`citystate:Chicago, IL OR citystate:Boston,MA OR citystate:San Diego, CA`.

The programmatic version is a [BooleanQuery](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery.html) composed out of several [TermQuery](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery.html)es.